# GAS adding a non domain member to google group doesnt work

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to create a spreadsheet to let user create his own google groups for mailing list purpose.

I can add domain's member to grups with this code:

```
function addGroupMember (groupEmail, userEmail,ruolo)  {
 var member = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: ruolo
 };
 try {
   member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
   Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);

 }catch(e){
   Logger.log("adding in:" + groupEmail + " failed  user email:  "+ userEmail + " role: " + ruolo + " error:"  + e);
}
```

But if i try to add a non domain's user (i can do it in group management) it fails with this error:

[16-08-12 14:54:13:113 CEST] adding in: mygropu@mydomain.it failed user e mail:  user@otherdomanin.it role: MEMBER error: Exception: Invalid Input: memberKey

Comment: Can you add them via web version? Do you have `Allow members external to this organization` selected?

Comment: Yes! i can add non domain address in web version, and yes external member is allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some test more, and found the clue!

The Exception: "Resource Not Found: email@otherdomain.com" rises up when the otherdomain is gmail.com and the mail address does not exist.

Using any other domain works even for non existent addresses! I think that G.A.S.  checks only for  his own domain addresses, but can't do it for other domains.

Answer (score 0):

As the error log shows exception `Invalid Input: memberKey`, it means that you may not able to give the real memberKey/ authentic memberKey.  `memberKey` is the user's or group priary email address, user's alias email address or the user's unique `id`

To get the `memberKey`, you can use the [`Members:get`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/get) to retrieves a group members properties.

HTTP request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/groupKey/members/memberKey
```

Response:

```
{
  "kind": "admin#directory#member",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "email": string,
  "role": string,
  "type": string
}
```

`id` is the unique ID of the group member. A member **id** can be used as a member request URI's **memberKEy**

Comment: does it mean i cannot add non domain address? but i can do it in web interface...

Comment: I can do it with "try it now" at https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/insert... Is there some difference between my code and the http request in your example? I didn't understand how to use the HTTP request in Google Apps Script....

Comment: I made some test more, and found the clue! 
The Exception: Resource Not Found: email@otherdomain.com rises up when the otherdomain is gmail and the mail address does not exist.
Using any other domain works even for non existent addresses! I think that G.A.S.  checks only for  his own domain addresses, but can't do it for other domains...(sorry i had to post in answer)